# выполнить скрипт на сетевом устройстве, создавая автоматически сессии ssh

Tags: linux, bash

На Ubuntu  по ssh пытаюсь запустить скрипт на сетевом устройстве со своей операционной системой на базе linux.

```
cat commands.txt | ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 root@10.1.30.94
```

в файле commands.txt содержится одна команда для ОС этого устройства (после планируется скрипт - цикл, выполняющийся на Ubuntu, который в процессе выполнения получает значения переменных с этого устройства, и многократно открывает и закрывает соединение).
После выполнения команды на Ubuntu предлагается ввести пароль при подключении к устройству, и после ввода соединение ssh закрывается, а на устройстве команда не выполняется.
При том, что если выполнить только

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 root@10.1.30.94
```

будет запрошен пароль и откроется соединение.

Мне нужно открыть соединение ssh на Ubuntu не вводя вручную пароль, и передать устройству последовательность команд из файла commands.
Подскажите пожалуйста, выполнив какую команду на Ubuntu я смогу это сделать.

Comment: `cat ... | ssh ... sh -` минус в конце существенен.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin на роутерах часто нет ссылки sh на ash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команды через ssh выполняются вот так

```
ssh user1@server1 'command2'
```

поэтому, Вам скорее всего нужно такое

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 root@10.1.30.94 $(cat command.cpp)
```